# LibGDX App Hanging on initializGlfw()

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl, glfw

I noticed that recently when I run my LibGDX game it takes a good 20 seconds to boot up which is strange because I'm only loading a few resources. I put breakpoints in my main method to pinpoint where the app was getting stuck, and it turns out it's getting stuck when I call this line:

`new Lwjgl3Application(new GdxGame(), config);`

In the Lwjgl3Application constructor, it is hanging on this method call:

`initializeGlfw();`

Which looks like this:

```
static void initializeGlfw() {
        if (errorCallback == null) {
            Lwjgl3NativesLoader.load();
            errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err);
            GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
            if (!GLFW.glfwInit()) {
                throw new GdxRuntimeException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
            }
        }
    }
```

In this method it gets stuck on `createPrint` and `GLFW.glfwInit()`. The print method looks like this:

```
public static GLFWErrorCallback createPrint(PrintStream stream) {
        return new GLFWErrorCallback() {
            private Map<Integer, String> ERROR_CODES = APIUtil.apiClassTokens((field, value) -> 0x10000 < value && value < 0x20000, null, GLFW.class);

            @Override
            public void invoke(int error, long description) {
                String msg = getDescription(description);

                stream.printf("[LWJGL] %s error\n", ERROR_CODES.get(error));
                stream.println("\tDescription : " + msg);
                stream.println("\tStacktrace  :");
                StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
                for ( int i = 4; i < stack.length; i++ ) {
                    stream.print("\t\t");
                    stream.println(stack[i].toString());
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

All of these methods come from the Lwjgl library. Does anybody know why my app might be getting stuck on these method calls?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and it seams to be tied to the machine you are on. I made a clean VS15 solution with GLFW and ran it on several different PCs to find that only my desktop had this issue. I also tested the LWJGL binding of GLFW and had the same results.

[EDIT] the wait happens in the glfwInit() call

```
/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit()) // stuck here
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
```

There is one post that I came across an archived [post](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/archive/index.php/t-175716.html) on the openGL forums that mentions an issue similar to this but it's fairly old and might be referring to a slightly different issue.

I can recommend to check that you are excluding your build folder from any antivirus, sometimes they see the generated executables as potential threats and thus might be slow however i dont believe that's your issue.

Sadly the only option that has worked for me was a clean install of windows, though the bug mysteriously stopped manifesting itself when I connected a VR headset and reappeared a couple days later. Hope you have better luck than me and dont have to clean install your OS and if you find a less cumbersome solution be sure to spread the word.

Comment: I've found that if my steam crashes, and then I try and load the game, it goes really slowly. If I just restart my computer, the problem goes away.